# How to grow image height more than the height of container so that image overlaps other elements/components?

Tags: css, angular, hover, css-transforms, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scrolling list of movie posters and when i hover over an image, the image grows in size but is only visible according to height of the container. I want the image to grow outside of the container overlapping other elements. I tried using 'position: absolute' on image, but then other images in the list dont behave as expected.

## list.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <h3>{{ heading }}</h3>
     <div class="scrolls">
          <div (click)="loadContent(content.id, content.type)" *ngFor="let content of list" class="imageDiv">
               <img [src]="content.imgSrc" />
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

## list.component.css

```
.wrapper { 
    background:transparent; 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999; 
    margin: auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

h3 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.scrolls { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height: 250px;
} 
.imageDiv { 
    margin: 0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 1200px;
    display: inline;
} 

.imageDiv img { 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999; 
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 250px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
        z-index: 1 !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    background: gray;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

## image-list

[image]

## image-hover

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you may want is to put `overflow: visible` on your `.imageDiv` class styling, or something similar at least.

This setting allows content to grow outside of its container, which is what you seem to want.

See the W3Schools [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).